# is it possible to implement LSTM with input shape (sample,timestep,timestep,feature)?

Tags: nlp, lstm, rnn, word-embeddings

I'm new to Keras. I am trying to implement this model https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1167 for document classification, and I want to use LSTM for getting sentence representation. I have trained vector representation separately with the skip-gram model on my dataset. now after converting each document to separate sentence and then converting each sentence to separate word and then converting each word to the corresponding integer in the dictionary, I have something for example like this for each document: [[54,32,13],[21,43,2]...[28,1,9]] which I should feed each sentence to an LSTM to get a sentence vector and after that I should feed each sentence vector to a diffrent LSTM on the higher layer in order to get a document representation and then apply classification to it. my problem is in the first layer. how should I feed each sentence simultaneously to each LSTM (therefore at each time step each LSTM should be applied to a word vector from each sentence) ?

Comment: Try explaining your problem precisely, probably by a single statement.

Comment: I just want to have a layer with an LSTM that could be applied to multiple inputs(multiple sentences in a document) at the same time in a way that each input(sentence) has multiple time steps (word) and then an output vector for each sentence.